# Encoding an Address that contains a null byte in a payload

Tags: exploit, metasploit

I am working on an SEH exploit. the problem I am facing here that all POP/POP/RETN addresses end with null bytes, so everything placed after it gets corrupted.

Is it possible to use Metasploit Msfencode to encode the address of the POP/POP/RETN instructions its self to get over the problem of the null byte ?

The exploit structure is: (300 bytes of junk + nseh + seh + 3000 bytes of junk)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Immunity Plugin mona.py,  developed by awesome guys at corelan.be . you can check  pop/pop/ret  combinations using that . Morever mona.py also provides with a skeleton to convert your exploit module to metasploit module hence porting it there .

Also  try   !mona  suggest to see the exploiting options after placing mona.py in Pycommands folder of immunity debugger . It might suggest you something else as well .

You can use msfencode but encoding will make payload longer and  300 bytes is too less .But you can try to see if it fits .

If non of the above works then you might have to do what Ditmar suggested .

Answer (score 1):

This question is impossible to answer accurately without a specific look at the binary or more detail about what you have access to.

In general, if your SEH address contains a null byte you should stick nseh&seh at the end of your payload for exploit simplicity. Having nseh be a jump up to your shellcode usually works fine with this, your problem may instead be fitting your shellcode into 300 bytes(that you have control over?).

There are [lists of techniques](https://thesprawl.org/research/seh-to-nseh/) you may try, but I still see you being limited to those 300 bytes.